# Populating a Dialog Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, spinner, android-alertdialog, android-dialogfragment

I would like to create a DialogFragment that has a title, then a message"Select Wifi" followed by a spinner. Below that, I would like another message that says "Enter nickname", and then an edit text field below that. And then two buttons that would return the strings of both the spinner and the edit text. I have this code so far, but I cannot figure out why it's not working...

```
public static class MyAlertDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    public static MyAlertDialogFragment newInstance(String title) {
        MyAlertDialogFragment frag = new MyAlertDialogFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("title", title);
        frag.setArguments(args);
        return frag;
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        String title = getArguments().getString("title");
        final EditText input = new EditText(getActivity());
        final Spinner sp = new Spinner(getActivity());

        return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                .setTitle(title)
                .setMessage("Select Wifi")
                .setView(sp)
                .setMessage("Enter nickname")
                .setView(input)
                .setPositiveButton("Save",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                            ((MainActivity)getActivity()).doPositiveClick();
                        }
                    }
                )
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                            ((MainActivity)getActivity()).doNegativeClick();
                        }
                    }
                )
                .create();
    }
}
```

It only displays the edit text file and the message for the edit text. So how can I add a spinner to this? Or is there a better way of implementing a dialogFragment that can display a spinner and a editText, with multiple messages? Perhaps even using hints in the spinner and edit text instead of messages? Also is there a way to populate a spinner in my main class and then use that spinner in my dialog? Thanks for any help.

Comment: why would you return a AlertDialog from a custom class that is extending a DialogFragment? You can use the custom class like a activity with xml files and setcontent view methods.

Comment: I tried to do it based off of the android documentation site. I'm still trying to learn. If I wanted a simple dialog that would return a value of a spinner and an editText, what should I use instead? Thanks for the quick reply. @IllegalArgument

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `setView()` method to set custom layout for the AlertDialog's **content**.

So just make a layout that suit your needs. In this case a LinearLayout that contains your views (messages, EditText and the Spinner). Let's say you named it `my_dialog.xml`, then you can use it like this:

```
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
    LinearLayout root = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_dialog, null);

    // get your Views with findViewById, and initialize them
    //
    // Spinner sp = (Spinner) root.findViewById()...
    // ...
    // ...

    return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
         .setTitle(title)
         .setView(root)
         .setPositiveButton("Save",
              new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                 public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                     // you can access you Views here 
                     // and gather the info that you need

                     // you can modify doPositiveClick to
                     // accept that info as parameters
                     // so the parent Activity can get it
                     ((MainActivity)getActivity()).doPositiveClick(param1, param2);
                 }
             }
         )
         .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
             new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                 public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                     ((MainActivity)getActivity()).doNegativeClick();
                 }
             }
         )
         .create();
```

With the custom view, you can still use the AlertDialog's built-in features (like title, positive/negative buttons, etc...).

Comment: Thanks! This is what I was looking for and is elegant and simple. @kupsef

Comment: I tried implementing this, but I'm getting errors on the inflator.inflate saying it cannot take arguments int. Also, the getActivity() calls are giving me errors. Any idea what could be going on? @kupsef

Comment: Well, inflate takes 2 paramters, I updated my answer according to that. What errors do you get with getActivity()?

Comment: It says that the method getActivity() is undefined for the type MainActivity. @kupsef

Comment: What are you doing in MainActivity? You should do this in your MyAlertDialogFragment. (Just as you have done in your question above.)

Comment: Ugh, I didn't even realize I accidentally deleted the top part of my code. Thank you very much. How did you learn android? @kupsef

Answer (score 2):

A very simple custom dialog fragment example here. This code is from one of my apps:

```
public class ClaimDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
Button buttonClaim;
EditText editTextClaim;
String profileId;
String status;
public static ClaimDialogFragment newInstance(Bundle bundle) {
    ClaimDialogFragment myFragment = new ClaimDialogFragment();
    myFragment.setArguments(bundle);
    return myFragment;
}
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dialog_claim, container,
            false);
    getDialog().getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getDialog().getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(
            android.R.color.transparent);
    editTextClaim = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editTextClaim);
    buttonClaim = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.buttonClaim);
    Log.d("point a", editTextClaim.getText().toString() + "");
    return view;
}
@Override
public void onStart() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStart();
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        profileId = getArguments().getString("profile_id");
    }
    buttonClaim.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                        "Please write your claim letter.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
        }
    });
}
}
```

And the relevant xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/dialog_background"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="8dp" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextClaim"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="4dp"
    android:background="@drawable/edittext_border_background"
    android:ems="10"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:hint="Cover letter for the claim"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:minLines="5"
    android:padding="4dp" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonClaim"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/button_black"
    android:paddingTop="8dp"
    android:text="/Claim"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

This is how i call this dialog fragment:

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity()
                            .getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    DialogFragment fragment = new ClaimDialogFragment();
                    fragment.show(ft, null);
```

Also note that you can use the newInstance() static method for a fragment.
Here's a snapshot of this code from my app:
[image]

Comment: Okay, I was thinking about dialogs in the wrong way. So it's better to have them in their own class that way you can edit the views using xml?

Comment: A dialog will always have a class it may be provided by others(android) or can be your own. This doesn't need to be in its own class but I like it that way to keep my code organized. Providing custom xml is for styling a dialog to your liking. There are very little options when using AlertDialog.

Comment: See my answer for that "very little" option:) In my opinion it is much easier to use AlertDialog, because of the features which it provides. (title, negative/positive button handling, etc...)

Comment: I wish there was a way to give two green check answers, thanks for all your help. @IllegalArgument